# how to arrange 3 divs(left/bottomcenetr/topright) inside div in html?

Tags: css, html

i have trying to achieve this

```
| Div     |                  |Div nav wrapper|
| logo    |                          
|container||  Div banar container            |
|         ||                                 |
```

i hv tried this

```
 <div class="grid_12">
        <!--logo_container start here-->
        <div id="logo_container">
            <a href="#" id="logo"></a>

        </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 57px" class="grid_13">
            <div id="banar_container">
                <a href="#" id="banar"></a>
            </div>
            </div>

        <!--logo_container end here-->
        <div id="nav_wrapper">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li class="current_page_item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">My Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LogOut</a>

                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--#nav_wrapper-->
    </div>
```

and the css are

```
.grid_12 {
width:940px;
}
 .grid_13 {
width:851px;
 }
#logo_container{
    float:left;
    margin-top:20px;}

#logo{
    background:url(../images/bp.jpg) no-repeat left;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    height:100px;
}
#banar_container
{
  float: left;
}

 #banar
 {
background:url(../images/Banner1.png) no-repeat left;
width: 851px;
float:left;
height: 71px;
 }

 #nav_wrapper {
position:relative;
display:inline;
float:right;
margin-right:25px;
margin-top:6px;

height:50px; 

}
```

its not coming that way.. so what should i do?

this is my complete code ... this is what i am trying but failing to do it ... so guys pls take a look at this and tell me my fault

guys i am still struggling with this

Comment: Are we talking about fixed widths or heights? A fixed container? or does everything has to be fluid?

Comment: @iMoses 1st div1 and div3 are fixed

Comment: @Drone That isn't your actual HTML is it?

Comment: maybe creating a fiddle to show us the exact problem would help...

Comment: @Th0rndike are u saying that i should put what i am getting now?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you'll find this example useful. Notice that, as you said, the size is fixed but still fluid relative to it's parent by using percentage.

HTML

```
<div id="example">
    <div class="box01"></div>
    <div class="box02"></div>
    <div class="box03"></div>
</div>
```

​CSS

```
#example {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

div.box01 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
}

div.box02 {
    float: right;
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

div.box03 {
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: #aaa;
}​
```

**[Code Example](http://tinkerbin.com/iq4VFduk)**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the values of your div width and height.

Check this **[DEMO](http://tinkerbin.com/DpNDZMUL)**

---

Updated **[DEMO](http://tinkerbin.com/BOnc8Fjr)**

Comment: this is exactly what i am getting now but i want that lower part to get upper

Comment: and my div2 height and width is not set

Comment: @Drone http://tinkerbin.com/GjPnU2Qs check this. div 2 height and width has been removed. wat do u mean by lower part??

Comment: lower part means div3 .. yes this is good for me about if u check my code i am not getting this

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like this:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
<div class="div1"></div><div class="div2"></div>
    <div class="div3"></div>
    </div>​
```

and CSS:

```
div{border:solid 1px black;}
.div1 {
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}

.div2 {    
    width:50px;
    height:18px;
    float:right;    
}
.div3 {
    width:250px;
    height:80px;
    float:left;
}
.wrapper{
    width:304px;
    border:none;
}​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4YX9H/)

Or maybe even something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4YX9H/1/ - width and height of div2 may be almost any (it just must be not wider than its parent)

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to realize you need more divs than just those three. That is to say, `div`s 2 and 3 need to have a parent that is a sibling of `div` 1. Try something like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rLDqc

HTML:

```
<div id="left">This is your div on the left</div>
<div id="center">
  <div id="main">Hello, this is the third div</div>
  <div id="right">This is the div in the top right</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#left{
  width:30%;
  background:red;
  height:100px;
}
#center{
  width:70%;
  background:blue;
  height:100px;
}
#left, #center{
  float:left;
}
#right{
  position:relative; 
  display:inline; 
  float:right;
}
#main{
  margin-top: 57px;
  float: left;
}
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#div1 {
width: 100%;
}

#div2, #div3, #div4 {
width: 33.3%;
float: left;
}

<div id="div1">
<div id="div2"></div><div id="div3"></div><div id="div4></div>
</div>
```

Change width of inside divs according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Most confusing job in web designing for me is to align divs like these but if you understand every aspect of float, display and some other properties important for layout designing then you can easily create such layouts.

Check this fiddle for an example 
http://jsfiddle.net/DeepakKamat/xQKXz/1/

The HTML :

```
<div class="container">
<div id="div1">Div 1</div>
<div id="div2">Div 2</div>
<div id="div3">Div 3</div>
</div>​
```

The CSS :

```
.container {backgroundcolor:yellow;display:block;width:400px;height:150px;padding:10px;}
.container div {margin:2px;color:white;}
#div1 {background-color:blue;width:20%;height:100%;border:2px dashed white;float:left;}
#div2 {background-color:green;display:inline-block;width:20%;height:70px;float:right;border:2px dashed white;}
#div3 {background-color:red;display:inline-block;width:76%;height:48%;border:2px dashed white;}​
```

I hope this helps you.